# ¿Como valido un checkBox desde una clase diferente en C#?

Tags: c#, checkbox

El problema que quiero resolver es el siguiente:

Tengo un formulario donde tengo un checkBox, y tengo otra clase que es un tipo de log que yo hice, la cosa es que en base a ese checkBox se va a ejecutar o no una serie de acciones por parte de la clase del log, como puedo evaluar ese checkbox desde esta clase?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Comment: No es una muy buena práctica acceder desde otras clases al estado de otras clases, igual deberías considerar el refactorizar tus clases para que uses mejor los conceptos de programación orientada a objetos, sobre todo el encapsulamiento.

Comment: Aunque no es el mejor diseño, si que se puede. Eso si, sin ver algo del código de la clase dónde está el checkbox es imposible responder. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la clase no accedes al checkbox como control de forma directa, se supone que debes pasale el valor del checkbox a esa clase de log.

Esta claro que definiras un parametro del tipo `bool` para esta tarea, algo como ser

```
public class Log{

   private bool _flag;

   public Log(bool flag){
      _flag = flag;
   }

   public void Write(string mensaje){

        if(_flag){
           //haces algo
        }
   }
}
```

desde el front seria algo como

```
Flag f = new Flag(checkbox1.Checked);
f.Write("mensaje");
```

como veras se le pasa el estodo del check a esa clase no el control, asi mantienes la separacion de responsabilidades de cada parte